# How do I create random matrix where each column is all zeroes except for one random row?

Tags: matlab, matrix, vectorization

I want to create a matrix of size `m`-by-`n` where all elements in a column are 0 except one element which is 1. That one element must be at a random position.

eg.

```
[0 1 0 0 0
 0 0 1 0 0
 1 0 0 1 0
 0 0 0 0 0 
 0 0 0 0 1]
```

Comment: For each column, you need a random number for which row the 1 is in. So you want n random integers between 1 and m. Does that help?

Comment: use `randi` for that...

Comment: @David I thought of that, but had to use a for loop to create the matrix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another idea I have is to create the identity matrix of size `m x m`, then use `randi` with a range from 1 up to `m` to create a vector of `n` elements long.  After, you'd use this vector to access the columns of the identity matrix to complete the random matrix you desire:

```
m = 5; n = 5; %// Given your example
M = eye(m);
out = M(:,randi(m, n, 1));
```

Here's one possible run of the above code:

```
out =

     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0
     0     1     1     0     1
```

Comment: you are right. using `randi` instead of `permute` enables you to get the same column several times. You can also handle the case of different number of rows/columns. nice answer!

Comment: @Shai - Thank you very much :) Yours is as well.

Comment: @Shai - I was about to mention that `randi` will certainly be prone to generate duplicates, so there will certainly be a case where there will be rows of the matrix that are 0... i.e.. not all of the generated values in `randi` are unique.

Answer (score 4):

To add some variety, here's another approach:

```
m = 4;
n = 5;
[~, result] = sort(rand(m,n));
result = double(result==1);
```

This gives, for example,

```
result =
     0     0     0     0     1
     0     1     0     0     0
     1     0     0     1     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: isn't `sort` a bit heavy here?

Comment: @Shai Totally agree. Hence the sort of disclaimer, "to add some variety"

Answer (score 4):

You can also use `rand` and `max` to do the job:

```
m=4;
n=5;
R=rand(m,n);
result = bsxfun(@eq, R, max(R,[],1))
```

On my machine it gave:

```
 1     1     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     1
 0     0     0     1     0
```

How it works: Generating a random matrix, `R`, and then setting to 1 the entry corresponding to the maximal element at each column. No need for `sort`ing.

---

Regarding the *original* answer of [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/33007079/1), since it uses `randperm` it is restricted to square matrix only, and it will only produce random [permutation matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix).
One possible way to correct his solution is to use `randi` instead of `randperm`:

```
result = bsxfun( @eq, (1:m)', randi(m, 1, n ) )
```

May give this output:

```
 1     0     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     1
```

---

As for the answer of [bla](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33003973/1714410), using [`accumarry`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) can save the use of `zeros` and `sub2ind`:

```
m=5; n=10;
R=randi(m,n,1);
A = accumarray( {R, (1:n)' }, 1, [m n] )
```

May give this output:

```
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     1     0     0
 0     1     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
 1     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     1
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

here's an example using `randi`:

```
m=5; n=10;
A=zeros(m,n);
R=randi(m,n,1);
A(sub2ind(size(A),R',1:n))=1


A =

 0     0     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1
 0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
 0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0     0     0
 0     0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html) with [`randi`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randi.html) for a one-liner, like so  -

```
full(sparse(randi(m,1,n),1:n,1,m,n))
```

Sample run -

```
>> m = 5; n = 6;
>> full(sparse(randi(m,1,n),1:n,1,m,n))
ans =
     0     1     0     0     0     1
     0     0     1     1     0     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: what if there is a different number of rows and columns? Moreover, your code will never produce a result like the one in the example posted in the question. Your code can only output a random permutation matrix.

Comment: substituting `randperm` with appropriate `randi` can help you generate random matrices beyond permutation matrices, also with different number of rows/columns.

Comment: I agree.  Replace `randperm` with `randi`, and your code will be solid.

Comment: you can see in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33007495/1714410) how replacing `randperm` with `randi` solves the problem.

Comment: @Shai Sorry, yes I didn't see the double `1s` in OP's sample output. Agreed, `randperm` won't the way to go here, so added one with a `randi` and `sparse`, check it out. Thanks for pointing out the bug!

Comment: I just love oneliners

Comment: @bla Thanks Natan! I remember that fact about you :)